# How to fetch videos/pictures from automatically generated albums?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using ALAssetsLibrary to fetch album contents from my iPad. I have created some custom albums and have successfully retrieved it's contents. But I can't retrieve the system generated albums like 'Recently-added', 'Recently Deleted' and 'Videos'. Any suggestions?